# How can hide some parameter from swagger spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I have a Student class and I need `id`, `name`, `email`, `dob`, `age` parameters. These parameters are shown on swagger as below.

[image]

I do not want id appear on the swagger documentation. How can I do that?

I have tried

- @Schema(hidden = true)
- @Parameter(hidden = true)
  But didn't worked

I want to see only below parameters on swagger

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "dob": "2022-12-19",
  "age": 0
}
```

Can anyone help me about that, please?

Comment: Separate your response and request classes rather than hide part of your api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, ApiModelProperty and ApiParam didn't exist. I found the solution on [documentation](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox). The solution is as below;

```
public class Student {
     @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
     private Long id;
}
```

Also thanks to @Waled Ahmad